# Should I connect 4 solar panels (3.6v 900/1A) in parallel, in series or independently to the PCB to gain better power outcome?

Tags: solar-cell, solar-charge-controller

Good morning,

I have 4 solar panels with 3.6v 900/1A each, ~3.4W.
I would like to connect them using a PCB to be able to charge an internal lipo battery, a smartphone or other devices.

My question is: should I connect them in series, in parallel or independently to the PCB to gain better power outcome?

Please bare in mind:

1. The panels will be displayed all at the same time or just one and the rest kept in the dark.
2. If connected independently, the wires will be respectively 9cm, 23cm, 36cm, 50cm, in the parallel or serial cases only less than 1cm each, except the first that will still be 9cm).
3. The possibility to connect all of them in series, bring the benefit to increase the voltage, a downside of these panels, but consider will bring the voltage input in a range of 2/14.4v, as when only a single panel is displayed the initial voltage when it could start to produce energy is ~2v.

The benefit I see in using an independent connection is a more efficient energy harvesting when only one panel is displayed (9cm wires) and the rest of the panels are kept in the dark.
In my understanding in this case the rest of the panel acts as a resistance.
The downside I see of this solution is the excessive wiring could cause the same problem when all panels are displayed as such long wires could increase the resistance as well.
Also it will span the range of incomming Amperage between few mA and 4A.
Thanks in advance for your advice
Andrea

Answer (score 1):

> just one and the rest kept in the dark.

In this case, you need to wire them in separately.

The next problem is how to combine them. Normally you'd do this with diodes, but at low voltage the overall loss could be high; use Schottky diodes or MOSFETs in "ideal diode" configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution PJC, if I may ask, why you suggest to keep them separately? it's for the resistance caused by the panels not producing energy? Regarding the diode, I always use a mosfet, it may cost more but definitly is more efficient than a diode expecially in 5v circuits.

Comment: Yes - the panels not producing energy behave like forward-biased diodes.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is… you connect them in series to a MPP (maximum power point) tracking converter :D

Solar panels have their quirky V/I curves, i.e. their output impedance is not constant but varies with the load. So for optimum efficiency clever circuits were designed to sink exactly the correct current depending on the voltage available. The result is then stepped down with a conventional buck regulator.

Why in series? Essentially panel are diodes, and there is some dispersion on the output voltage, so putting them in series somewhat solves the issue (I don't know if there's something like cell balancers for solars).

The other reason is that stepping down with a switching converter is the most efficient operation (boost and buck boost are way less efficient). Also in series wiring is somewhat reduced.

I don't know of many of these converter built as ready-to-use ICs; usually you use an adequate buck converter and trick the current feeback network with an external network. Search around, there is a lot of material about them.

Comment: Thank you Lorenzo, it may need to be boost/buck, because when only one panel is on display it produces only 2/3.6v 100/1000mA

Comment: Of course, in the end you can use whatever converter you like. The non-inverting buck boost is a superset so it will work too. Maybe it's not easy to find as 'solar specific' but it could work. Also you began with attaching FOUR panels:D

Comment: Thanks again Lorenzo